# Make nav-bar stretch to fit content

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 pages for my site. One a forum, another is my homepage. I have the homepage all setup, but the forum will require a bit of modification to the nav bar. I have the nav bar from the homepage mirrored to the forum so that the styles match nicely, but I made the forum wider because the forum needs more space for content and tables. I have tried numerous times to do this, to no avail.

Since the forum is not a static page, I have put the homepage on JSBin instead. They both use the same exact nav bar. This is Bootstrap 3, by the way.

Here is what I want it to look like (sorry for not embedding in post, need 10 rep): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZWIt.png

Here is the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/fexowifica/1/

I just need to know how to make that extend out wider like seen in the image, but it won't actually be applied to the homepage nav bar, it will be applied to the forum nav bar that is seen in the image.

Thanks!

Comment: You have `<div class="container">` change that to `<div class="container-fluid">` for 100% width (minus the padding), if you don't want the padding, then add a `<div class="row">` which adds `margin-left:-15px` and `margin-right:-15px` to clear the padding from the container.

Answer (score 0):

just update your css

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .container{
   width:100%;
}
```